# How do I use the graph API to get a listing of all Azure AD groups of which a user is a member?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I can't seem to find the API call to make to check to see if a user that has authenticated themselves is a member of a specific Azure AD group.  Retrieving a list of all Azure AD groups the user is a member of would be fine as well.  I assume this would be done through the Graph API but I can't seem to find the API I would use for this.  How do I get a list of all Azure AD groups the currently authenticated user is a member of?

Comment: I'd assume this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http (note, read Graph API thoroughly since it is quite complicated, based on my experience)

Comment: lambda23 is correct. And this API call also lists the AAD role groups (`"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole"`) for the user.

Comment: @lambda23 Do you mind adding an answer?

Comment: @AllenWu just added the answer

Comment: @AllenWu, does this command Get-MgUserMemberOf also retrieve the Azure roles as well ?

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer and comments mention using memberOf. However, in most cases you want to use transitiveMemberOf instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-transitivememberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

memberOf only returns groups that the user is **directly** a member of whereas transitiveMemberOf respects group nesting.
For example, if User is a member of GroupA and GroupA is a member of GroupB then memberOf will only return GroupA but transitiveMemberOf will return both GroupA and GroupB.

Answer (score 0):

The (v1) Graph API that you're looking for is listed under **Users > Groups > List memberOf** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), as confirmed by Allen on the comment. This API will also list the Azure AD role groups for the user.

Note: Just for a general rule, even if the document looks complicated, operation on any resource is listed on the root of Graph API documentation. If you're accessing a property of a user, look at Users. That will help navigating yourself through the documentation.

Another edit: this might be handy for exploring the Graph API https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer